# How to load a different application in CodeIgniter with same session?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter 3 and try to manage multiple applications.
The structure is like this:

```
applications
    - app_1
    - app_2
    - app_n
system
user_guide
index.php <-- locates to app_1
app_2.php <-- index.php with parameters for app_2
```

app_1 does the login job which works pretty fine.
When I am logged in I want to switch to app_2 with the same session.
How do I create a link to navigate to app_2?
Already tried this but it does not redirect me to app_2.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>app_2.php">app_2</a>
```

Comment: Store it in DB....

Comment: use codeigniter controller if you have same domain

Answer (score 0):

Using codeigniter 3 in application/congfig folder
/config.php write session name as all application same

set session same name in CI and one session destroy so auto all session destroy.

app_1

```
   $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
```

app_2

```
  $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
```

app_3

```
  $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
```